# Offset x axis in ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'd like to create a ggplot2 plot with the bars being on the negative side and the positive side of the x axis like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"),
  var2 = c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=var1, y=var2, fill=var1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

with the slight difference that the values are all positive. as an example we add 10 to each data point in `df$var2` and now want to display the relative change around the mean of all values - value 10. the plot should look the same with the exception of the values for the y axis.

```
df2 <- df
df2$var2 <- df2$var2 + 10
```

How can I plot df2 to look like df? I don't like to change the labels on the y axis using `breaks=` and `labels=` as I have many different plots with ever changing values.

Any help is highly apprechiated!

EDIT:
To comment on @alistaire 's concerns: I generally agree, nevertheless, I think there are circumstances where such a graph is suited and not necessarily misleading.
If - for instances - I like to display the relative enrichment or depletion around a mean, but at the same time want to **convey the information what the actual mean is**, than I think such a graph can be quite helpful.

For example: See this figure in Nature Genetics (doi:10.1038/ng.3286)

[image]

Legend(a): **Percentage of fragments** containing GWAS SNPs that interact with a promoter, **segregated by individual disease or trait subclass.** The histogram shows the relative enrichment or depletion of each subclass, as compared to the total catalog of 8,808 SNPs analyzed, with data taken from 1,651 independent studies. The **average association across all SNPs** is shown **as a percentage.**

Comment: **What you're asking for is a misleading graph.** So don't do this: `ggplot(df2, aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = var1)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = var1, yend = mean(var2)), size = 25, show.legend = FALSE)`, even though you _could_. Add `geom_hline` to your original instead, if you like: `ggplot(df2, aes(x = var1, y = var2, fill = var1)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(var2)), colour = 'blue')` Or center your data and make exactly your original graph.

Comment: Thanks alistaire, works nicely! Also, I addressed your concerns and updated the post, so it becomes clearer what I intend to do with this kind of graph.

Comment: That's centered data (the last option I suggested) with a label to show where the center is—the other labels are relative to the mean and are not actual values. You could make that graph by centering with `scale` and setting the label with `scale_y_manual`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @alistaire's comment, with which I agree, you could also try using different geoms for the actual values and the differences, for example something like

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "grey70") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = pmin(var2, mean(var2)), 
                    ymax = pmax(var2, mean(var2)), 
                    colour = var1), size = 1) +
  guides(colour = FALSE)
```

which would give you a plot like
[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding this idea! Great thinking. Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (legitimate imho : I want to plot seasonal ratios with an axis at 1 (neutral element…))

Using the `barplot` function in the `graphics` package

```
    barplot(df$var2-10,offset=10)
```

Works fine for me.